# Facebook like button is liking wrong url

Tags: wordpress, facebook, redirect, button, facebook-like

First off, I saw similar posts already, but they weren't exactly what I am asking.

I used the Facebook Dev to create a like button for my website, stuck the code in and the the button showed up. The only issue is that it likes the wrong url when I click the button.

I'm pretty sure the issue is that I have it set to redirect automatically from mydomain.com to the most recent post. I think this is gumming up the works with the like button and causing it to like mydomain.com/mostrecentpost instead of simply liking mydomain.com.

Is there a way to correct this issue without having to get rid of the redirect (because that isn't an option)?

Sorry if that was a little wordy, wanted to make sure I explained the issue fully.

Comment: do you have the og tags on your page? Also, for the like button do you pass the href ad the permalink to your page? If you provide a link to the page, it would be helpful to debug.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this whole thing. Www.onceuponasidewalk.com

Comment: It is happening because in your facebook like button code you are specifically saying to like a particular page. You can remove the href parameter from your facebook like button code.

I mean try to change your facebook like button code to and see if that works. `<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=267618486682748" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

Comment: It comes backs with an error that says the parameter href is required.

Comment: then you need to pass the url of current page to it. it would be something like 

`<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php url_encode(the_permalink()); ?>send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;widt‌​h=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font&amp;heig‌​ht=35&amp;appId=267618486682748" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

Comment: Now I feel like I'm being pretty needy, but that code hides everything after where the button would show up.

Comment: Change `url_encode` to `urlencode`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to correct this issue without having to get rid of the redirect (because that isn't an option)?

Either don’t redirect *in those cases* where the user agent header of the request points to it being [Facebook’s scraper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#bestpractices);

or set the canonical URL of `http://example.com/mostrecentpost` to just `http://example.com/` using the appropriate Open Graph meta tag. (Although that would mean you would not be able to like a single post any more, because all of your posts would just point to your base domain as the “real” website; so the first is probably the better option.)

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to use the og meta tags, I'm a total rookie at the whole website design thing. Any chance you could explain it like you would to a five year old?

Comment: Okay, scratch that, I tried the meta tag and either I am putting them in the wrong place or that isn't working. If it helps, this is my site: [link](http://www.onceuponasidewalk.com).